# Alternative to for loop in R for adding previous rows iteratively

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have a large dataset for which I want to get the value of each row plus the previous row. With a for loop, it is fairly simple but with my large dataset, it takes much longer. I've been told that apply with a function is MUCH faster, but I don't know how to write a function and I can't find examples of similar problems.

```
#set up example with 10 rows
v=rep(sample(100), 10)
a=sample(100)
a=a[1:10]
mat=cbind((v/10)[1:10], a)
mat=as.data.frame(mat)
#order by first column from greatest to smallest
mat=mat[order(mat[,1], decreasing=TRUE),]
#run for lop
for (i in 2:nrow(mat)){
        mat$a.cum[i]<-sum(mat[i-1,3], mat[i,2])
        }
mat$a.cum[1]<-mat$a[1] # add value for first row
```

I tried a vectorized solution but clearly it doesn't work:

```
mat$a.cum[2:nrow(mat)]<-mat[1:(nrow(mat)-1),3]+mat[2:nrow(mat),2]
```

I got as far as this trying apply but it doesn't even work the way I thought it would...

```
apply(x, FUN=function(i) x[i-1,3]+x[i,2], MARGIN=1)
```

This is essentially the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548550/use-function-instead-of-for-loop-in-r-substracting-previous-rows-iteratively-wi) I ran into earlier but the proposed vectorized solution doesn't work (as far as my skills can tell) in this case so I'm back to trying to figure out how to write functions for iterative examples.  Since each row in the output data frame has dependencies upon earlier rows and they trickle down iteratively, I *think* vectorizing wouldn't work in this case (similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725801/avoiding-for-loop-in-r) but the answer doesn't get at what I'm trying to do). Possibly, it can't be done with a function given the dependencies upon earlier rows... but I'm hoping it isn't the case for the sake of speed.

Comment: Don't you just want a `cumsum` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a base function `cumsum` which gives you the cumulative sum of a vector:

```
mat$a.cum <- cumsum(mat$a)
```

example:

```
cumsum(1:10)
[1]  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55

cumsum(rep(1,10))
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
mat$a.cum=0
mat$a.cum[-1]<-cumsum(mat$a[-1])
mat$a.cum[1]<-mat$a[1]
```